# "Необычный" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: словообразование, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные, частицы

*Я (не)обычный доктор.*

Как пишется частица не со словом: слитно или раздельно? Вроде как мы можем заменить синонимом это слово, но здесь также напрашивается противопоставление.

Comment: Здесь еще напрашивается контекст, без него нельзя  выбрать верный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое общее решение – это выбор **утверждения или отрицания**, а всё остальное – всего лишь формальные признаки или приемы, в какой-то мере помогающие решить эту конкретную задачу.

Здесь эти приемы не помогут, если мы **не видим ситуацию** (нет контекста).

**Вариант 1. Отрицание.** Частица НЕ относится к словосочетанию.

– *Обычный доктор вряд ли это посоветует...*

– *Я **не обычный** **доктор**.*

**Вариант 2. Утверждение противоположного признака.** Слитное написание приставки НЕ. Значение слова указано в словаре.

**НЕОБЫЧНЫЙ**,  Не такой, как все, как у всех; непривычный, особенный. Н. тип мужчины. Лицо у него н-ое. Н-ая тишина. Н-ое волнение отца. Н-ая обстановка.

– *Мне посоветовали обратиться к вам.*..

– *Хорошо. Только имейте ввиду, я **необычный** доктор.*

Так что сюжет этой истории не слишком ясен, но любопытен.

Но, может быть, есть и другой контекст?